# Different results from ifort and gfortran when defining my own TYPE

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm new to Fortran, but am generally finding that I can do most things that I could with C or Matlab, once I get my head around modules and types. However, I'm stumped by this difference in results, depending on whether I use gfortran (gcc version 4.6.2) or ifort(13.0.2). Gfortran gives me the results I expect, but ifort gives me 3 blank lines! Any ideas why?

```
module define_structures
implicit none
private

public modelling_params

    type modelling_params
        real, dimension(:), allocatable :: freqs
        real, dimension(:), allocatable :: offsets      
        complex, dimension(:), allocatable :: data
    end type modelling_params   
end module define_structures

program main

use define_structures
    implicit none

    type (modelling_params) :: S

    S%data = [(1,1) ,(2,3), (3,1)]
    S%freqs = [1, 3, 7]
    S%offsets = [100, 200, 300]
    print *,S%data
    print *,S%freqs
    print *,S%offsets


end program main
```

Here's the output from compiling with gfortran

```
(  1.0000000    ,  1.0000000    ) (  2.0000000    ,  3.0000000    ) (  3.0000000    ,  1.0000000    )
1.0000000       3.0000000       7.0000000    
100.00000       200.00000       300.00000
```

And with ifort, I just get 3 blank lines, though it compiles fine!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for reallocation of allocatable variables on assignment in `ifort` is enabled when the `-assume realloc_lhs` command line option is passed to the compiler. If you insert the following immediately after the first assignment:

```
print *, allocated(S%data)
```

you would see `F`, which means that the allocatable field is not allocated when assigned to. The code works as expected with `-assume realloc_lhs`.

Comment: Exactly as you say, Hristo. Adding `-assume realloc_lhs` as a compiler option makes it work as expected. I'm curious as to why I didn't get a warning for this from the compiler, though.

Comment: If you tried to run with runtime checking enabled, you should get an error when assigning to an unallocated array.